# How to display section only using sectionmark

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using `\sectionmark` in my document. How can I hide section text in the main body and display only the `\sectionmark` in the header. As the repetition can be seen in the attached image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[paper=executivepaper,margin=0.75in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{MyBlue2}{RGB}{30,63,111}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[MyBlue2] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-0.75in)$);
    \node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\LARGE, minimum size=0.75in, inner xsep=0.75in] at (current page.north west) {\rightmark};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[MyBlue2] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.75in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large, minimum size=.75in, inner xsep=0.75in] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{footer.PNG}};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.65in, inner xsep=0.75in] at (current page.south east) {\textbf{Page:} \thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Executive Summary}
\lipsum


\subsection{ABC}

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your `MWE` in executable format....

Comment: Rather than placing the colored boxed section title in the headers and then seeking to hide the section title in the main text, why not place the section title with colors and box in its normal place? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23659/91556

Comment: Besides, your method will force you to start each section in a new page (to avoid conflict in the header). And if that's what you want, you can still start each section title in a new page in its normal position (with all the colors and boxes that you want).

Comment: MWE added in the question now